# stop a twisted reactor after a gatherResults has finished

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

new to twisted and just trying some deferred stuff out. I have the following code that makes up a list of 100 deferred calls - each waiting a random time and returning a value. That list the prints the results and finally terminates the reactor.

However, I'm pretty sure the way I'm stopping the reactor is probably... not great.

```
__author__ = 'Charlie'

from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
import random

def getDummyData(x):
    """returns a deferred object that will have a value in some random seconds
    sets up a callLater on the reactor to trgger the callback of d"""
    d = defer.Deferred()
    pause = random.randint(1,10)
    reactor.callLater(pause, d.callback, (x, pause))
    return d


def printData(result):
    """prints whatever is passed to it"""
    print result


def main():
    """makes a collection of deffered calls and then fires them. Stops reactor at end"""
    deferred_calls = [getDummyData(r) for r in range(0,100)]
    d = defer.gatherResults(deferred_calls, consumeErrors = True)
    d.addCallback(printData)

    # this additional callback on d stops the reacor
    # it fires after all the delayed callbacks have printed their values
    # the lambda ignored: ractor.stop() is required as callback takes a function
    # that takes a parameter.
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())

    # start the reactor.
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm assuming that by adding a callback:

```
d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
```

to the gathered results actually adds that callback on all the deferred items?

if so then there is probably a more elegant / correct way to do it?

Cheers!

Comment: This is a fine way to do it.

Comment: Side note: `_` is the idiom for an ignored variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm assuming that by adding a callback:
>       d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
>   to the gathered results actually adds that callback on all the deferred items?

This isn't the case.  `gatherResults` returns a *new* `Deferred`.  It's just like any other `Deferred` you might come across.  Its `addCallback` method does the same thing as usual: adds one function that will be called at one point in one callback chain.

The reason everything is nice and regular and unspecial like this is that `gatherResults` takes care of all the logic necessary to *only* give that regular `Deferred` that it returns a result after all of the input `Deferred`s have a result.

So, feel free to use `gatherResults` just like you're use any other `Deferred`-returning API.  It's not special!

That said, starting with Twisted 12.3 there's a handy utility that you might want to use for this sort of thing - `twisted.internet.task.react`.  Here's what your `main` function would look like if you used it:

```
def main(reactor):
    """makes a collection of deffered calls and then fires them. Stops reactor at end"""
    deferred_calls = [getDummyData(r) for r in range(0,100)]
    d = defer.gatherResults(deferred_calls, consumeErrors = True)
    d.addCallback(printData)
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from twisted.internet import task
    task.react(main, [])
```

And notice that you could change `getDummyData` so that it doesn't depend on the global reactor either:

```
def getDummyData(reactor, x):
    """returns a deferred object that will have a value in some random seconds
    sets up a callLater on the reactor to trgger the callback of d"""
    d = defer.Deferred()
    pause = random.randint(1,10)
    reactor.callLater(pause, d.callback, (x, pause))
    return d

def main(reactor):
    """makes a collection of deffered calls and then fires them. Stops reactor at end"""
    deferred_calls = [getDummyData(reactor, r) for r in range(0,100)]
    d = defer.gatherResults(deferred_calls, consumeErrors = True)
    d.addCallback(printData)
    return d
```

And now your code does't need any `twisted.internet.reactor` imports at all.

You could also use `twisted.internet.task.deferLater` in `getDummyData` to save a bit more typing:

```
def getDummyData(reactor, x):
    """returns a deferred object that will have a value in some random seconds
    sets up a callLater on the reactor to trgger the callback of d"""
    pause = random.randint(1,10)
    return deferLater(reactor, pause, lambda: (x, pause))
```

Comment: wow - thanks for the very detailed answer. I'll dig though this tomorrow.